# Get Keyboard / Mouse Input in Java

Tags: java, input, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get the user input without GUI Listeners or Scanner class?
Something like this:

```
if (Input.isKeyDown(KeyCode.VK_A)) {
    // Do something
}
```

In Unity3D you can get the Users input using this way.

Best regards
Morph

Comment: Simply you cannot. To capture the events you need GUI controls.

Comment: Unity3D will be implimenting listeners or similar behind the scenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Keys.html

You will find what you want.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: The link points to a page that contains an interface created for Input in some backends (desktop, GWT, etc.).

It may be useful for what you want.

Comment: If you could explain why or how to use that link (or even what that link points to) this would be a much better answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyPressListener implements KeyListener {

    // when a key is pressed
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        // the key you pressed
        char k = e.getKeyChar();

        // prints out what key you pressed
        System.out.println(k);   
    }

    // when a key is typed
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }

    // when a key is released
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    }
}
```

this will get you keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

You can only capture inputs in the context of your application. Else how could you know the user was not inputing on an other application?

In Java you can either use GUI (Swing or JavaFX) or console (`System.in.read()`) standard inputs.